# Suppose $|g(x)| \le x^4$, then find $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x)}{x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Suppose $|g(x)| \le x^4$,for all $x$, then find $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x)}{x}$.

I did it as follows:

$0 \le |g(x)| \le x^4$, for all $x$

$0 \le \left|\frac{g(x)}{x}\right| \le |x^3|$ for all $x\neq 0$

Also, $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}0=0$ and $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}|x^3|=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}x^3=0$.

Then by the Squeeze Theorem, we have $\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}\frac{g(x)}{x}=\lim\limits_{x \rightarrow 0}\left|\frac{g(x)}{x}\right|=0$.

I think it's right. I'm just not sure if I can consider $x \neq 0$ in the Squeeze Theorem.

Comment: You probably want to say $\lim_{x\to 0}x=0$ in one of the later lines, but generally it's okay.  I find that the squeeze theorem makes more sense for me if I use inequalities on the limits being compared.

Comment: @abiessu That's because I considered $0$ as the constant function.

Comment: Then the only thing I think I would add is a negative side to force $\frac{g(x)}x$ to $0$ from that side as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is completely fine indeed

$$\left|\frac{g(x)}{x}\right| \to 0 \iff \frac{g(x)}{x}\to 0$$

For the last doubt recall that when we consider the limit $x\to 0$, by definition, we are considering $x\neq 0$ therefore the assumption is fine.

Comment: For sure, I was just affraid of this because I had to divide by $|x|$, which implies $x \neq 0$. Thank you so much!